# Codeception getting timed out after 30 seconds when using REST

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I am trying to post a file via code exception but it keeps getting timed out after 30 seconds.

How to handle it?

```
$I -> sendPOST('submit?key=someauthKey', [
    'ae_id' => '106016',
    'be_id' => '1',
    'me_id' => '81',
], [
    'file' => codecept_data_dir('download.png')
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set execution time of PHP Script

Use the follow code in top of you PHP file. The maximum execution time, in seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

**NOTE** `set_time_limit()` function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: Does not work. Stil gets timed out.I think i have to provide settings in codeception config.But can't find the settings